# When can a polygon pass through a 1-dimensional door?

Tags: geometry

[image: Example]

If $AB$ is the door width, when its possible for a regular polygon to pass through the door?

Intuitively, the minimum polygon "width" must be lesser than $AB$, so I think the answer to this question is when $2 \times a < AB$, where $a$ is the measure of the apothem.

Am I correct? If so, how can I prove that $2 \times a$ is the minimum "width" of the polygon?

Comment: Turn it sideways: it is infinitely thin.

Comment: Yes, you're right. What about through an 1-dimensional door?

Comment: Is the shape constrained on the plane, or can you rotate it above and below?

Comment: The shape is constrained on the plane.

Comment: For regular $n$-gon with even $n$, the condition is indeed $2a \le AB$. If you can move the $n$-gon pass the door, then at certain time, the centroid will cross $AB$. At that moment, the intersection of the regular $n$-gon with $AB$ will be a line segment of length $s$ such that $2a \le s \le AB$. This shows the min-width $\ge 2a$. When $AB = 2a$, it is clear how to push the $n$-gon through the door. So the min-width $= 2a$. No idea what is the right condition for odd $n$.

Comment: The problem is considerably more intricate if the polygon is not regular, and not convex.

Comment: Yes if the diameter of circumferential circle of regular polygon is less than the width of the door. For hexagon this diameter is twice as the measure of side. so what you claim is true only for hexagon.